# What React hook to use to make it re-render the list each time function is called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sorting

I have a useState as following:

```
 const [drivers, setDrivers] = useState(useSelector(selectFilteredDrivers));
```

Here drivers is an array we can map through.

I have a sorting function that sorts the list of drivers:

```
const sortDrivers = useCallback(
(sortBy: string) => {
  const sortFunction = (
    a: DeliveryDriver,
    b: DeliveryDriver,
    sort: string,
  ) => {
    if (sortBy === 'desc') {
      return Number(a.isAvailable) - Number(b.isAvailable);
    } else {
      return Number(b.isAvailable) - Number(a.isAvailable);
    }
  };
  const sortedListOfDrivers = drivers.sort((a, b) =>
    sortFunction(a, b, sortBy),
  );
  console.log('sortedList', sortedListOfDrivers);
  setDrivers(sortedListOfDrivers);
},
[drivers],
 );
```

As you can see I sort the list and set the list to sortedListOfDrivers.
Down below I map through drivers list to return Driver component for each driver:

```
 const rows = drivers.map(driver => (
  <Driver
  driver={driver}
  key={driver.driverId}
  handleRowOnClick={driverDetailClickHandler}
/>
```

));

If you are wondering, rows is something I pass to Table component as a prop.

```
    render (
        <Table headers={headers} rows={rows} />
   )
```

The function is passed down as a callback and attached to onClick.
When I console.log drivers after sorting, it shows that array of drivers is updated accordingly after click, so sorting functionality works great behind the scenes.

The problem is that in UI my list remains the same (like before sorting) and it doesn't re-render the list to make it sorted after the click.

NOTE:
Not sure if it has to do something with the issue, but for some reason, UI refreshes to show sorted list when I start typing something in input field which has nothing to do with the sorting function.

How do I make it update the list of drivers when function is executed (button clicked)?

I've tried placing my mapping part in useEffect(). It didn't work.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: if you're using redux you don't need to put `useSelector` inside `useState`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> The sort() method sorts the elements of an array **in place** and returns
> the sorted array. The default sort order is ascending, built upon
> converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences
> of UTF-16 code units values.

It means that `sortedListOfDrivers === drivers` is `true` and `setDrivers` thinks that nothing changed. You should create a new array to avoid that:

```
setDrivers([...sortedListOfDrivers]);
```

Note: `drivers.sort` changes the variable without notifying react. So it doesn't update your UI until something other triggers a rerender.

Comment: Genius, man. Thank you so much